# YARP Dynamic Destination Based on current user claims

Tags: .net-7.0, ms-yarp

Does someone know if it's possible to change my YARP cluster destination at runtime based of a value from my current user's claims.

The claim is not the value but rather the key to find the value in a cache.
The cache sits on top of my DB so help with performance.

I tried using ConfigFilters but these are singletons and don't have access to the users claims.

Would this have to be done using middleware, if so : How?
Or would a better approach be to use the singleton config filter already injected, when authorization happens to the push the correct destination into that singleton?

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic routing like that your best bet is to use the direct forwarding API: https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/direct-forwarding.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using the tenantid of the access token, to route a request in this sample:
https://github.com/henrikwh/Tenant-Reverse-Proxy/

At runtime I am looking up the tenantid, and then routing to the mapped destination. Azure App Configuration to store the YARP configuration, enabling YARP proxy instances to subscribe to config changes, providing a runtime reconfiguration (like adding a new route or tenant).